# CSS - lines and squares appearing out of nowhere

Tags: html, css

I have a weird issue where lines or squares are showing up out of nowhere and I believe its related to overflow: scroll

Example 1: I have a div that as I scroll up and down a vertical line starts to appear and it gets more and more visible. It's a white line right to the left of the content.

Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECri5.png

After: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrMD6.png

Here is the css for that div:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
padding: 50px;
height: 200px;
overflow: scroll;
```

Example 2: In this example a grey square appears randomly in the top left of the div. Sometimes it shows up, sometimes it doesn't and when it does show up, it shows up after a random amount of time, it's not always there immediately.

Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0IVa.png

After: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrwCC.png

Here is the css for that div:

```
display: block;
float: left;
width: 14.342%;
padding: 5px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
overflow: scroll;
```

If I remove overflow: scroll these things go away.

Anyone ever experience anything like this or have any idea what's going on?Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you able to share this question in a fiddle or codepen?
It is quite difficult to understand the question with the poor visuals. 
Also please post the full relative code for this question.

Comment: Better than CodePen of Fiddle, is StackSnippits, use the `<>` button in the question editor to add an interactive example in the question. A [MCVE] is always helpful.